# Delphi XE3 Project failed to debug/run on OS X 10.10.5

Tags: c++, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe, delphi-xe3

I have a Delphi XE3 project (in Windows 7) that worked fine before, but I haven't started it for a year, recently when I run the project again, the remote debugger of Delphi seems not working (connection is ok) well, and shown this error message upon project start:

> > Debugger Assertion Failure "!" invalid remote api"" in .\rdbg_proxy.cpp at line 3844

I did update OS X from 10.8 to 10.10.5 during that period, so I assume that could be the reason to make the debugger failed? XE3 doesn't support OS X 10.10.5 maybe?

How to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately only the current Delphi version is maintained for iOS development. Every new release of OS X, X Code or iOS require changes in Delphi, so if you don't have the latest Delphi, then don't update any of these.

Comment: So I have to update to the latest version of XE in order to make it work?

Comment: I do iOS development, which is more sensitive to Apple changes than OS X development, but upgrading OS X and/or X code has caused problems for me several times, and I am quite sure that XE3 is too old to work with  OSX 10.10.

Comment: So each time Apple upgrade, we also need to upgrade XE? It is very pricey.. nightmare.

Comment: Each time Apple upgrade, EMB fix only the current version of Delphi, and chances are that you haven't got the current version, as EMB have made new Delphi versions every 6 months, so far. They recommend a subscription...

Comment: great, so when Xcode7 and iOS9 release, XE8 would stop working again? crazy.

Comment: What do you expect? You want EMBT to go back and make updates for a 6 or 7 version old development tool because you want the latest and greatest OS features but don't want to pay them for providing the tools to use them?